# Split list in special chunks

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have the following problem. I have a list like:

```
>>> l = list(range(20))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> # What I want:
>>> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9] , ...]
```

How can I get my list into such k pieces with length 4 in the most pythonic way? I feel like I miss something obvious here. I am fully aware of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) but still have no clue...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you expand on what you are struggling with? The referenced answer provides a range of very Pythonic approaches to this problem.

Comment: No, no and no! Note that the last element of each chunk is the same as the first element of the next chunk!

Comment: `[l[a:a+4] for a in range(0,len(l),3)]`

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher well, you're not chunking your list, you're generating a pattern *similar* to your list.  The two problems are not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct copy of an answer to question you have posted link to. The only change is the step in `xrange` - from `n` to `n - 1`:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n - 1):
        yield l[i:i + n]


list(chunks(range(20), 4))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11, 12], [12, 13, 14, 15], [15, 16, 17, 18], [18, 19]]
```

Comment: Finally someone who read the question correctly. Thanks for the answer and hell yes, I could have figured that one out for myself...Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
zip(*[iter(list(range(20)))]*4)
```

Comment: Not what I want. Note that the last element of each chunk is the same as the first element of the next chunk!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = range(20)
b = [a[i:i+4] for i in xrange(0, len(a), 4)]
print b
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```